# Confused about basis for $Im A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm confused about how to find the basis for $Im A$ consisting of standard vectors $E_i$ if
$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I notice $A$ is already in rref form.

I've read that the basis for the image of $A$ is the linear independent column vectors of $A$, which would give me $E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4, E_5, E_6, E_9.$ I've also read that the basis for the image of $A$ is the "row space" of $A$, which I'm assuming is the linearly independent rows, aka $E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4, E_5, E_8.$ The answer in my book is $E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4, E_5, E_8.$ So does this answer fit into the idea "The image of TA is generated by the columns of A." in the answer here: [Find Basis of Image of a Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647868/find-basis-of-image-of-a-matrix) ? Where is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pick the line vectors (and not column vectors) of $A$, and find a maximal independent subfamily thereof.

To see why, remember that $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ is generated by the images under $A$ of any basis of the domain. Take the canonical basis $e_1,\dots,e_8$, you get $A(e_i) = (A_{1,i},\dots,A_{9,i})$.

Of course, you can exclude any line vector that's identicaly $0$.